# Stripe Payment Link to Woo Commerce Order in Zapier: address and customer information

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, webhooks, zapier

I am trying to create a payment link that collects a customer's address upon purchase in order to use it to place an order through WooCommerce with our third-party partner. I know this is possible, but when creating the Zap, I am having trouble with the trigger. I want it to trigger whenever a product is purchased off a payment link, but I only want it to trigger for a specific payment link. For example, if a customer purchases product A, then I want the trigger associated with product A to activate so an order with that specific product can be put through.

How can I get the information from a specific transaction so I can create an order with that information within a WooCommerce Create Order action? I was told that code and webhooks could solve this issue, but I am not sure how to set this up properly with Webhooks by Zapier. Anything helps, and I would love to discuss with anyone on how to solve this problem.